# Prove that $\phi(a^k)=a^{k-1}\phi(a)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\phi(a^k)=a^{k-1}\phi(a)$ such that $a,k \in \mathbb{N}$

So far I now that $\phi(a^k)=\phi(a^{k-1})\phi(a)$. I'm not sure how to conclude that $\phi(a^{k-1})=a^{k-1}$. It seems false just by seeing that if $a=3$ and $k=3$ then $\phi(a^{k-1})=6\not=9=a^{k-1}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prime factors of $a^k$ are the same as those of $a$.  So
$$\phi(a^k)=a^k\prod_{p\mid a^k}\Bigl(1-\frac1p\Bigr)
  =a^k\prod_{p\mid a}\Bigl(1-\frac1p\Bigr)
  =a^{k-1}a\prod_{p\mid a}\Bigl(1-\frac1p\Bigr)=a^{k-1}\phi(a)\ .$$